# Diophantine Factorial Equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, factorial

Prove that there exist pairwise distinct positive integers $a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{1000}$ such
that
$a_0! = a_1!a_2! \cdots a_{1000}!.$

Comment: You could do something with induction and $$  (n!-1)! \; n! = (n!)! $$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  You can let somebody else choose $a_1$ through $a_{999}$, then you can choose $a_0, a_{1000}$ to succeed.